# Entity Framework Many to Many Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm making movie database webapp, but I have no idea how can I make a search using many to many, if I want for example to search movie by genre, how can i do it? and how can i make entity framwork to search for dynmic number of genre, like i can search with 1, 2 or more genre. like filtering.

Here is what I got so far

```
var query = from movie in db.Movies where movie.Genres.Any(g => g.GenreID == 2) select movie;
```

the `g.GenreID = 2` is currently hardcoded, but how can I make it to accept to GenreID to search? I try `g => g.GenreID == 2 && g.GenreID == 3` but it doesnt return any movie. How can I make it to return a movie when both condition is true?

**Here is my table and at the bottom is what i want to accomplish.**

```
Movie
---------------------------
MovieID MovieTitle
1       The GodFather
2       Analyze This
3       The GodFather Part II

Genre
---------------------------
GenreID GenreName
1       Comedy
2       Crime
3       Drama

MovieGenre
---------------------------
MovieID GenreID
1       2           // The GodFather -- Crime, Drama
1       3           //
2       1           // Analyze This -- Comedy, Crime
2       2           //
3       2           // The GodFather Part 2 -- Crime, Drama
3       3           //


Result
---------------------------
Search: Drama
Result: The GodFather, The GodFather Part II

Search: Comedy
Result: Analyze This

Search: Crime
Result: The GodFather, Analyze This, The GodFather Part II

Search: Crime, Drama
Result: Result: The GodFather, The GodFather Part II

Search: Crime, Drama, Comedy
Result: none
```

**Here is my model and context**

```
Movie.cs

public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}


Genre.cs

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}


AppDbContext.cs

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext() : base("MovieConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var genreIds = new List<int> { 2, 3 };

using (var db = new YourContext())
{
    var movies = db.Movies;

    foreach (var genreId in genreIds)
    {
        movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g.GenreID == genreId));
    }

    var queryResults = movies.ToList();
}
```

Comment: it work, but i need more testing. there is some minor fix about var movies so I change it to IQueryable<Movie> movies. thanks, i been looking for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'OR' condition like this `g => g.GenreID == 2 || g.GenreID == 3`

using 'AND' condition in `g => g.GenreID == 2 && g.GenreID == 3` means that it would return records that have both genreid 2 and 3.A single record cant have more than one genreid.

if you need to return movies that has both genreid's,
you need basic query something like this

```
select MovieID
  from MovieGenre
 where GenreID in(244,246)
group
    by MovieID
having count(*) = 2 ;
```

'2' is the number of genre id's passing.Change this into corresponding Linq

Linq may be something like this.This linq is untested and may contain errors

```
var query = from movie in db.Movies
              where movie.Genres.Any(g => g.GenreID == 2|| g.GenreID == 3)
              group movie by movie.MovieID into m
              where m.Count() == 2
              select movie.MovieID
```

Comment: I can't use or. What I want is to return a movie that contains those genres. Like if I search 2 and 3 genreID, it will return a movie that has those genres.

Comment: i get the idea, i think this will also work, but im having a problem, when i add the **group movie by movie.MovieID into m where m.Count() == 2** it gives syntax error The name 'movie' does not exist in the current context. it makes squiggly line in the last part select movie.MovieID

Comment: i think the answer posted by OJ Raqueño will work perfectly for your scenario

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing method with query syntax.
Perhaps this works

```
var Movies = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g.GenreID == 2).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: but what if i search for more than one genreID? and the it throws 'bool' does not contain a definition for ;FirstOrDefault'

Answer (score 0):

So, if 2 and 3 are selected it will return the movies which are in genre 2 or 3.

```
public ActionResult Search(IEnumerable<int> selectedGenreIds)
{
   var moviesInSelectedGenres = db.Genres.Where(x => selectedGenreIds.Any(z => z == x.GenreId)).Select(x => x.Movies);
}
```

Comment: this doesnt solve my problem, but thanks, what i want is lets say a movie called The Godfather have genre of 2 and 3, and another movie like Analyze this have genre of 1 and 3, so if I search for genreID 3, it will return both movies, but if i search for, genreID 2, it will return The Godfather, then if i search genreID 1 AND 3, it only return the movie Analyze this. What I want to achieve is some sort of filtering.